# node http performance under windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I'm trying to measure the performance of my application and bumped into an issue with the   Windows system.
When I'm bombarding the app below via the http://localhost:8001/ address, I get about 4 thousand requests. However, if I start doing the same from another laptop, I get only ~150 requests per second. The network is a home WiFi with about 45Mbps speed.
What is more important, the amount of instances does not make any difference, the speed is always the same 150 requests per second. I've disabled the firewall on the machine with the server application but still see the same 150 requests per second.
Please, help me understand this issue, what is going on?

UPD: I create the load using `ab -c 10 -n 1000 http://<host>:8001/` where `<host>` is either the name of another laptop or `localhost`.

```
const http = require('http');
const cluster = require('cluster');
const numCPUs = 8;
const requestListener = function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    if (req.url === '/test') {
        res.end(JSON.stringify(content)); // some big payload
        return;
    }
    res.end('some small payload');
}

cluster.schedulingPolicy = cluster.SCHED_RR;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    console.log(`Master ${process.pid} is running on ${numCPUs} CPUs`);

    for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
    }

    cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
        console.log(`worker ${worker.process.pid} died`);
    });
} else {
    const server = http.createServer(requestListener);

    server.listen(8001);
}
```

Comment: The wifi is probably the bottleneck. Try with an ethernet cable if you can

Comment: "some big payload" - how big? You can see local traffic consumption. If it and wifi bandwidth are comparable then that's it

Comment: Big - it is generated to check how these things depend on the payload size. Say, these 150 requests are measured on about 10-20 bytes payload

Comment: What is generating the client load?  Is the client load coming from a browser?  Or from some client-specific stand-alone nodejs code?  Can you show us how the client load is generated?

Comment: I generate the load using the following command `ab -c 10 -n 1000 http://other-end:8001/` where the `other-end` is another laptop connected to the same wifi with the disabled firewall or just `localhost`.